# How to avoid code repetition for multiple Cards in a ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ListView which consists of 3 Cards. Each Card has a Text and different fontSize. How can I write a single code for one Card and call it in the ListView  for the remaining 2 Cards with different Text and fontSize. 
This will help me save extra lines of Code. The code below

```
 Widget homeBody = Container(
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: 200.0,
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            onTap: () {},
            child: Column(
              // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'About',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Vishwapreneur',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 200.0,
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            onTap: () {},
            child: Row(
              // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Smart Sociothon',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                // Text(
                //   'Sociothon',
                //   style: TextStyle(
                //       fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                // ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 200.0,
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            onTap: () {},
            child: Column(
              // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Entrepreneurship',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Development Cell',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Share what you've done so far

Comment: I've added the code now. Sorry for the inconvenience. I have used SizedBox in which i have put in the Card to give it sizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your `text` along with `textSize` to your card.

The example below will give you an idea

```
ListView list(){

    Map<String, double> items = new Map();
    items["A"] = 14.0;
    items["B"] = 24.0;
    items["C"] = 32.0;

    return new  ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return myCard(items.keys.toList()[index], items.values.toList()[index]);
        },
    );
  }

  Card myCard(String text, double textSize){
    return new Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize),),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What if I also want different background image for each card apart from the Text and the fontSize, in that case would map work?